# How to get pixel color from Matlab imaq.VideoDevice step() output

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, infrared

I'm using step() in imaq.VideoDevice, but can't find description of format of step() output.  Am using thermal infrared camera, and want to filter for specific temperature range.

So, I want to use step() on each frame, and then search the frame for pixels within specific thermal range.  And obviously need to know the X,Y of each pixel, too.

My goal is to filter pixels from a frame and leave only pixels within desired temperature.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer:
step() outputs ROW X COLUMN X pixel_color
where pixel_color = index 1 is the amount of red in the pixel.
pixel_color = index 2 is the amount of green in the pixel.
pixel_color = index 3 is the amount of blue in the pixel.

For example, for color of pixel at X, Y = 5,10  = row 5, column 10
then:
amount of red = (5, 10, 1)
amount of green is = (5, 10, 2)
amount of blue is = (5, 10, 3)

EXAMPLE USAGE THAT DISPLAY A FRAME WITH RED COLUMN AND GREEN ROW........

% Get a video frame:
load('handshakeStereoParams.mat');
            videoFileLeft = 'handshake_left.avi';
            readerLeft = vision.VideoFileReader(videoFileLeft, 'VideoOutputDataType', 'uint8');
            frameLeft = readerLeft.step();
        live_scene_player = vision.VideoPlayer('Position', [20, 600, 850, 500],  'Name','LEFT');

% Make green horizontal stripe at row 10 on the image:
        frameLeft(10,:,1)=0;        % remove red from stripe
        frameLeft(10,:,2)=255;      % turn on all green
        frameLeft(10,:,3)=0;        % remove blue from stripe

% Make red horizontal stripe at column 10 on the image:
        frameLeft(:,10,1)=255;      % remove red from stripe
        frameLeft(:,10,2)=0;        % turn on all green
        frameLeft(:,10,3)=0;        % remove blue from stripe

% display it:
        step( live_scene_player, frameLeft);          % originally from frameLeftRect

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get the information on temperature and color from your IR camera. Look up the documentation it probably says which values correspond to what pixel values. At that point you just create a mask for each frame. something like this (Assuming the values from the ir camera is "grayscale', meanign there is only one channel)

```
highest_temp = 200; %just a random number
lowest_temp = 50;

my_mask = (im <= higest_Temp) & (im >= loest_temp);
```

`my_mask` is a logical array with a 0 when the pixel is outside the range, and a 1 (true) when the pixel is inside the range. IF you want to apply the mask to the image just multiply them together (and take care of units, here I assume the IR camera is <16 bits)

```
masked_im = uint16(im .* double(mask));
```

I would also use trigger function rather than `step` If I'm not mistaken the trigger action should take only 1 image/frame by default. so Make a loop, grab a frame, do your processing, then go to the next loop iteration, over and over. Hope that helps